# Ease-in works for both text and background but ease-out only works for text. Why?

Tags: html, css

Ease-in only works for text and background but ease-out only works for text but not background.

```css
article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #fffff;
  color: #00000;
}

article .topnav {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: background-color .9s ease-out;
  transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
}

article .topnav {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transition: opacity .9s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .9s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity .9s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .9s ease-in;
}

article:hover p.topnav {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.topnav {
  visibility: invisible;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p class="topnav">I am topnav</p>
</article>
```

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yulius/pj5omea1/11/).

The idea is so that when I hover in and out of , both the text and the background eases in and out together.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide code instead of just posting an url to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting both transitions on the unhovered state, thus the second one is overwriting the first rule. You need to apply transition rules to both unhovered and hovered state.

```css
article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #fffff;
  color: #00000;
}

article p.topnav {
  opacity: 0;  
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all .9s ease-out;
}

article:hover p.topnav {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: all .9s ease-in;
}

.topnav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p class="topnav">I am topnav</p>
</article>
```

Comment: You mean like this:
article .topnav {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: background-color .9s ease-out;
  transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .9s ease-in;}

article .topnav {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transition:opacity .9s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .9s ease-in;}

article:hover p.topnav {
  opacity:0.7;
  background-color:#808080;
 transition:background-color .9s ease-out;
 transition:background-color .9s ease-in;

 transition:opacity .9s ease-out;
 transition:opacity .9s ease-in;
}

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing in your comment to see, I added an example.

Comment: Sorry @Paul I am a newbie, I pressed enter to get to the next line, but it just posted before I am done. By the way, I don't see your example, where can I find it?

Comment: Reload the page if you don't see the link saying something like "This answer has been edited, Click to reload". In my answer, I edited your code to work, it's a minimum example of how to make it work.